# Побитовые операции для создания отказоустойчивой системы из 3 жестких дисков

Tags: булева-алгебра

Доброго времени суток. Некоторое время назад прочитал статью про бэкап данных.
Суть статьи про три диска. 
На первый диск записываются некоторые данные. На второй диск записываются другие некоторые данные.
А на третий диск записывается результат побитовых операций(or,xor, and и т.п) для первых двух дисков.
В итоге если ломается 1 из 3 дисков, можно запросто восстановить данные опять же проведя побитовые операции на 2 уцелевших дисках.
Подскажите пожалуйста какие побитовые операции нужно применять и в каком порядке.
Проблема в том что статью то прочитал, но забыл сохранить в закладках...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как

```
a xor (a xor b) == b
```

для каждого `a` и `b` (потому что операция `xor` *ассоциативна* и `a xor a == 0` и `0 xor b == b)`,

**примените операцию `xor`**:

```
диск_3 = диск_1 xor диск_2
```

Тогда

```
диск_1 = диск_2 xor диск_3
диск_2 = диск_1 xor диск_3
```

потому что

```
диск_2 xor диск_3 = диск_2 xor (диск_2 xor диск_1) = диск_1
диск_1 xor диск_3 = диск_1 xor (диск_1 xor диск_2) = диск_2
```

Comment: спс, все заработало, лайкнул ваш ответ.

Comment: Не стоит - спасибо за лайк.